# Expanding complex expression and replacing variables in the result

Tags: replacement, complex, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

When I'm finished expanding my expression I would like the result to be expressed again in terms of the original variables (like α, S1, T1, T2). I've tried [`replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/replace.html), but can't seem to have good results. Any suggestions?

```
c = ((1 + I) Pi)/D1;
τ = I τy;
u0 = ((1 - I) π τ)/(D1 *ρ0* f);
ζ[h_] := (π h)/D1;
α[h_] := (Cosh[ζ[h]]*
      Cos[ζ[h]])^2 + (Sinh[ζ[h]]*Sin[ζ[h]])^2;

S1[h_] := (Cosh[ζ[h]]*Cos[ζ[h]])/α[h];
T1[h_] := (Cosh[ζ[h]]*Sinh[ζ[h]])/α[h];
T2[h_] := (Cos[ζ[h]]*Sin[ζ[h]])/α[h];

vg[h_] := (
    2*π)/(ρ0*f*D1)*((1 - S1[h])/(T1[h] - T2[h])*τy) - 
   ug*(T1[h] + T2[h] - 2*π*h/D1)/(T1[h] - T2[h]);
ugc[h_] := ug + I vg[h];
uec[z_, h_] := 
  u0*Sinh[c*(z + h)]/Cosh[c*h] - ugc[h]*Cosh[c*z]/Cosh[c*h];
uc[z_, h_] := uec[z, h] + ugc[h];

expr = ComplexExpand[uc[z, h], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
```

Comment: Something like this: but I'm not sure why I don't see S1/T1/T2 
`rules = {S1[h_] :> Inactivate[S1[h]], T1[h_] :> Inactivate[T1[h]], 
   T2[h_] :> Inactivate[T2[h]], \[Alpha][h_] :> 
    Inactivate[\[Alpha][h]], \[Zeta][h_] :> Inactivate[\[Zeta][h]]};
FullSimplify[ReplaceRepeated[FullSimplify@expr, rules]]`

Comment: Any symbol that appears on the LHS of a `Set` or `SetDelayed` can never appear outside a held expression since the specified replacement will always be automatically done. If you want to use these symbols in expressions, use `Equal` rather than `Set` or `SetDelayed` to define equations then solve the system of equations for the desired variables.